# SQL query giving incorrect results for average customer age

Tags: sql

I'm not really sure whether my SQL query below is correct but let's say that there are three tables as described below:

```
table customer:
    name
    passport
    age
table menu:
    type
    item
    price
table breakfast:
    passport
    item
```

I need to find the average age of the customers who ordered fried rice for breakfast. The common field between `customer` and `breakfast` is the `passport column so my current attempt is to join using that and average the customer ages:

```sql
SELECT AVG(c.age) FROM customer c, breakfast b
    WHERE c.passport = b.passport
    AND   b.item = 'Fried Rice';
```

That, however, is giving incorrect values some of the time.

Thinking it may need to use *distinct* values, I instead tried this but it also gave incorrect results:

Should the query below instead be:

```sql
SELECT AVG(c.age) FROM customer c
    WHERE c.passport EXISTS IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT b.passport FROM breakfast b
            WHERE b.item = 'Fried Rice'
    );
```

What is the problem with these, and what would be the correct query? Even pointers would help out here.

Comment: I'm not sure if your title could be more meaningless (or more redundant) than it is now. Your title should be something that describes the problem or question, and that should be useful to future readers. It should not contain the tag information (which the tag provides). Removing the tag information leaves "language query" (and actually "query" is in SQL), which does absolutely nothing to provide information that will be useful in the future. Please [edit] your question title so that it has some sort of informative content.

Answer (score 2):

With your first query, think of what would happen if I was meeting Taylor Swift for breakfast one morning<sup>(a)</sup> but I was *really* hungry and decided to have two helpings?

Imagine the rows returned for that by the first query:

```
pax    50
pax    50
taylor 26
```

Clearly, the average age of `pax` and `taylor` is `(50 + 26) / 2 = 38`, but averaging those *three* rows would give you `(50 + 50 + 26) / 3 = 42`.

The key here is the phrase "the average age of the customers", meaning it shouldn't matter how *many* helpings of fried rice a person had, they're still only a *single* customer.

The second query is closer in that it attempts to make sure that customers are *not* duplicated in the results, at least once you fix the errant use of `exists in` as per the below commands:

```sql
create table customer(name varchar(20), passport integer, age integer);
create table breakfast(passport integer, item varchar(20));
        
insert into customer(name, passport, age) values ('pax', 1, 50);
insert into customer(name, passport, age) values ('taylor', 2, 26);
    
insert into breakfast (passport, item) values (1, 'fried rice');
insert into breakfast (passport, item) values (1, 'fried rice');
insert into breakfast (passport, item) values (2, 'fried rice');
    
select * from customer;
select "";
select * from breakfast;
select "";
    
select avg(c.age) from customer c, breakfast b
    where c.passport = b.passport
    and   b.item = 'fried rice';
    
select avg(age) from customer
    where passport in (
        select distinct passport from breakfast
            where item = 'fried rice'
    );

drop table customer;
drop table breakfast;
```

Running that script shows the difference (annotated with `#`):

```bash
pax@styxbank> sqlite3 mydb.sdb < mysql.sql
pax|1|50     # These are the two customers.
taylor|2|26

1|fried rice  # These are the three breakfast rows.
1|fried rice
2|fried rice

42.0  # This is based on averaging the three rows,
38.0  # whereas this is averaging the unique customers.
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Yeah, as if *that* could ever happen :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your second query has the right idea as Taylor Swift's date mentioned, but it is malformed.  You can use `WHERE column in (list of values)` or `WHERE EXISTS (query or condition)`:

```
SELECT AVG(c.age)
FROM customer c
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM breakfast b
              WHERE b.item='Fried Rice'
                AND b.passport = c.passport)
;
```

Or:

```
SELECT AVG(c.age)
FROM customer c
WHERE c.passport IN (SELECT DISTINCT b.passport
                     FROM breakfast b
                     WHERE b.item='Fried Rice')
;
```